# Problema con iconos en mi terminal de vscode

Tags: vscode

Me encuentro utilizando zsh en mi terminal de vscode, le instalé ohmyzsh a mi terminal que utilizo la cual es iterm2 para macOS. El problema que tengo es que al momento de querer visualizar los iconos en zsh dentro de mi vscode esta no los muestra y se ven como acontinuación:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y me gustaría que se viera de esta manera, como la veo en el iterm2:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2):

Problema solucionado, ingresar en Visual Studio Code, acceder a Open User Settings JSON y en ese apartado agregar `"terminal.integrated.fontFamily": "meslolgs nf"` y problema solucionado.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]